# How to describe two different objects?

Tags: word-choice, conjunction-reduction

How to describe two different objects:
(Assume: one apple and one banana here) 
"There are an apple and banana here." or
"There are an apple and a banana here." ??

Comment: Are you asking for a phrase/word to describe the contrasting characteristic of two different things? A common idiom for that is "Apples and Oranges", the twins are only similar in appearance, in nature they are really apples and oranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will use **is** if the object is in singular. 
Eg:

**There is an apple and a banana here.**

You will use **are** if the objects are in plural.
Eg:

**There are apples and bananas here.**

More details on verb agreement is given [here](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/six-rules-for-making-subjects-and-verbs-agree/).