# articles before two adjectives

Tags: word-usage, articles, conjunction-reduction

If we describe a child as friendly and enthusiastic where should we use article?Is it she is a friendly and enthusiastic child or she is friendly and a enthusiastic child,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to describe two different objects?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237292/how-to-describe-two-different-objects)

Answer (score 2):

> she is a friendly and enthusiastic child

is short for:

> She is a friendly child. She is an enthusiastic child.

while

> she is friendly and a enthusiastic child

is short for:

> She is friendly. She is an enthusiastic child.